# Getting an average from an unconventional date and time string

Tags: google-sheets

I have an Alexa Routine where the date/time when I say goodnight is tracked in a Google Sheet - so I can see when I actually went to bed. Yup, everything can be tracked and measured these days!

But the entries are *super* weird and unhelpful strings, not dates and times:

Sample data:

```
January 23, 2021 at 11:29PM
January 25, 2021 at 12:03AM
January 25, 2021 at 11:27PM
January 26, 2021 at 11:17PM
```

Alexa just dumps these unconventional date/time strings into A1-A??? on the first tab.

My goal - to show my average bedtime each month. Usually I can hack my way to an answer but I'm having trouble converting these into the month/year and times, let alone finding a way to average them.

Turning to those who have madder skills than me!

Appreciated as always.

Comment: Alexa is dumping the dates directly to the google sheet or are you? what does it display in the Formula bar when you click on an entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (in C1 given that your data starts from A2:A):

**UPDATED:**

```
= QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
            IF(LEN(A2:A), {
                MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D+") & 1),
                REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D+"),
                IF(TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")) > 0.5,
                    TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")),
                    TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")) + 1)
            }, "")),
        "Select Col1,Col2 ,avg(Col3) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1, Col2 Order By Col1 asc label Col1 '#', Col2 'Month', avg(Col3)
        'Average bedtime'
        ")
```

[image]

**Spreadsheet demo: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19e719AxBpyFn2Ev-8CqxCWZU-RqDdiaEdeqJDuEBsNo/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Hello Nabnub. Look at my answer. It is same result with simpler formula

Comment: It is true. I delete my answer.

Comment: This is great, did the trick. Apparently my average time to bed is much later than I thought. Good to know! Thanks for your really substantial response to this, Nabnub!!

Comment: If the response was useful to you, you can mark it as accepted and up vote it, it helps others find inspiration both from your question and from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said your raw data strings run A1:A. That being the case, you could place the following in cell B1 (where Col B and Col C are both otherwise empty):

`=FILTER(SPLIT(A:A," at ",0,1),A:A<>"")`

This will create a real date in Col B and a real time in Col C for each string in Col A. From there, you can easily perform other functions. For instance, assuming you've got the above formula in B1, you could place the following in, say, E1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({DATE(YEAR(B:B),MONTH(B:B),1),IF(C:C<0.5,C:C+1,C:C)*1},A:A<>""),"Select Col1, AVG(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL AVG(Col2) ''"))`

... then format Col E (**Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *mmm yyyy*) and Col F (**Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *h:mm am/pm*).